# Laravel - Vue.JS - Auth JWT vs Laravel Auth with Axios

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js

I want to understand difference JWT Auth vs Laravel Auth with Axios.

In Laravel Auth with Axios, we can use standard middleware and things from Laravel Auth. Can someone explain me why People always choose JWT? It's got something than Laravel Auth with Axios don't have? We can always set a variable in JS with auth true/false when user it's logged in by Laravel (it checks session/cookies for that) and check that variable before route change?

Comment: Jwt is token based aithentication and stateless . Not require session.

Comment: Did you read any article ? You should share what is not clear with example ?

Comment: You may find it useful to read the documentation from [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport)

Comment: I know that JWT is token based authentication and i know how it's work, but we can authenticate user with laravel auth with axios in vue.js application (in single page application). I want know if JWT it's better or worst?

Comment: The answer is the same with most of the question in the computer field: 'It depends'. You should read more about: stateful vs stateless.